# Google Analytics subdirectory filter not showing any traffic (incorrect)

Tags: google-analytics

I've created a Google Analytics view to track all visits to www.example.com/wordpress/*

This is the filter:

[image]

However, this view shows no traffic.

If I look at the default view that doesn't have this filter, there are visits to the /wordpress/ subdirectory included in the stats.

What is wrong with my filter please?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this might be a better fit?

[image]

Comment: Thanks Raymond. When I edit the filter to match your example, I click Verify Filter and I receive "Filter Verification: This filter would not have changed your data. Either the filter configuration is incorrect, or the set of sampled data is too small."